# How to create a time-driven trigger in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers, timer

I have a table in my database (postgres), that keeps in it the user accounting trace. I need to create a trigger that will perform a clean up at a given amount of time (let's say 30 minutes.) Is it possible to do that from postgres, or do I need to use something else? (By something else I mean C or Java or any other programming language that can sleep for a given time).

Comment: You can use [pgAgent](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pgagent.html) for event scheduling.

Comment: Thanks for link, but I don't know how to insatll pgAgent in my machine (I'm running Centos6.2)

Answer (score 3):

Without PgAgent, things like this can be done using a cron script.

In both cases the periodic thing will be running from a different context
(database owner, superuser, postgres), and in a separate transaction, obviously.